# Sweetalert2: Remove inline style applied to elements

Tags: sweetalert2, tailwind-css

I use Tailwindcss alongside the sweetalert2. and use this config to generate an alert:

```
customClass: {
  ...
  image: 'hidden md:inline-block',
},
```

I use ImageUrl for Alert config. So my `swal2-header` contains:

```
<img class="swal2-image hidden md:flex" src="/path/to/image" alt="" style="display: flex;">
```

Due to the `hidden` and `md:flex` classes, I expect the image to be hidden in small resolution and become visible for `md` breakpoint, but the inline `style="display: flex;"` disables my `hidden` classes and actually is replaced with it. So how could I remove or disable the inline class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Masih, the author of SweetAlert2 here.

I just published the new version of SweetAlert2 (`v9.13.1`) which doesn't set `style="display: flex;"` on the image.

Cheers!